# What is an Android device's main UI screen called?

Tags: android, tablet

I am lost with the proper terminology that I should use to define a project when dealing with app developers.  For context, I am working on a business effort to develop an e-learning tablet delivered as modularised apps on the android platform; some preloaded and others to be downloaded.

I would like to know the proper turn-of-phrase to describe this scenario;
When the tablet boots up a "main app" is activated and locks out the usual "landing page". Within this "main app" will be other apps and features.

Is this difficult to code? Appreciate all replies, helpful inputs and other views that you may have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is has nothing to do with actually programming.

Comment: Isn't this just kiosk mode?

Answer (score 4):

The "usual landing page" is a "Home Screen Launcher" or, specifically, an app containing an Activity which is registered to handle `android.intent.category.HOME`

Replacing that by installing your own implementation (a very crude example can be found in the Android SDK samples) can indeed be a "soft" way to special-purpose an Android device.  However, if you install this onto a normal secured device, by selecting this home app from a chooser menu in place of the stock one, a user can always undo your operation by re-selecting the original, either after accessing settings from the status bar (not part of the home screen app, so not under your control) or by rebooting in safe mode.

To permanently change the device UI, you will need to customize the installation of Android, either by finding devices with something like the `fastboot oem unlock` option, finding some that ship with "engineering" builds (common with no-name imports), or formally working with the device manufacturer.  Of course, if you use one of the generic unlock methods to get your code on there, a clever user can do the same to revert it. Beware also that in customizing Android the first thing you have to do is figure out how to get back to a working base - many times the system you will find installed on a cheap device has uncertain origins, and merely replicating it to *begin* customization can be a challenge.   Fortunately, if you only want to replace the home launcher you don't really need sources - but if you want to start changing the status bar, etc, you will find it hard (but not impossible) to do so without source.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I did not know about the android.intent.category.HOME. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "main app" so don't you that term. a screen you interact with is called a Activity in Android and a collection of Activities is. The App itself. There can't be another app inside one app. 
So I'm guessing by features you mean functionality like test taking or results. Those can be separate activities themselves and user can navigate to them through home screen(Main app)